# Creating a masonry effect with varying height rectangles

Tags: c#, unity3d

The following is used to create a masonry effect with varying height rectangles. How can I simplify and make this more elegant in Unity?

```
private float startX = 0.0f;
private float startY = 0.0f;
private float posX = 0.0f;
private float posY = 0.0f;
private float prevWidth = 0;
private float prevHeight = 0;
private int index = 0;
private int currentCol = 0;


private void AddCard(int index, int col, float width, float height)
{
    GameObject goCard = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(pfCard00);
    PackedSprite psCard = goCard.GetComponentInChildren<PackedSprite>();

    goCard.name = "QuestItemCard" + index.ToString();
    goCard.transform.parent = goCardContainer.transform;
    psCard.height = height;

    if (currentCol != col) 
    {
        posX += width;

        posY = 0;
        prevHeight = 0;
    }

    // placement
    posY += (prevHeight / 2) + (height / 2);
    goCard.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(startX + posX, startY - posY, goCard.transform.position.z);

    if (currentCol != col)
    {
        prevWidth = width;

        currentCol = col;
    }

    prevHeight = height;
}
```

Usage:

```
AddCard(0, 0, 100, 100);
AddCard(1, 0, 100, 100);
AddCard(2, 0, 100, 100);
AddCard(3, 0, 100, 200);

AddCard(4, 1, 100, 100);
AddCard(5, 1, 100, 100);
AddCard(6, 1, 100, 100);
AddCard(7, 1, 100, 200);
```

Comment: A couple of questions before answering:  Do you want gaps? It looks like the taller cards at the end (#3 and #7) will lift the next row by 100 units leaving a gap. Is it possible to have varying height cards in one row?  And what do you want to do with the indices? you're not using them now.

Comment: A good start would be making index a static field and incrementing it each time you call AddCard. Then you don't have to pass that value in at all (or remember it somewhere)

Answer (score 5):

Consider splitting the code that increments the column into a separate method that can be called manually. Now you do not have to pass in column or row, and index can be incremented by the `AddCard` method. This greatly simplifies usage and allows you to make use of a for loop.

```
private float startX = 0.0f;
private float startY = 0.0f;
private float posX = 0.0f;
private float posY = 0.0f;
private float prevWidth = 0;
private float prevHeight = 0;
private int index = 0;
private int currentCol = 0;


private void IncreaseColumn()
{
    currentCol++;
    posX += width;
    posY = 0;
    prevHeight = 0;
}

private void AddCard(float width, float height)
{
    GameObject goCard = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(pfCard00);
    PackedSprite psCard = goCard.GetComponentInChildren<PackedSprite>();

    goCard.name = "QuestItemCard" + index.ToString();
    goCard.transform.parent = goCardContainer.transform;
    psCard.height = height;

    // placement
    posY += (prevHeight / 2) + (height / 2);
    goCard.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(startX + posX, startY - posY, goCard.transform.position.z);

    prevWidth = width;
    prevHeight = height;

    index++;
}
```

Usage:

```
var columns = 2;
var rows = 4;

for(int x= 0; x< columns; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y<rows-1; y++)
    {
        AddCard(100, 100);
    }
    AddCard(100, 200);
    IncreaseColumn();
}
```